# Auto renewable subscription on iOS7 with sandbox

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase

In `iOS6`, when we purchase a product, we can get a receipt from transaction. Then we send this receipt to app store and verify. If verification result is `valid(status=0)`, a `base64-encoded` string named `latest_receipt` will be returned. Then we can store and use this new encoded receipt to do verification next time.

Everything is just fine until changing to `iOS7`. Receipt in transaction is deprecated, instead, we need to get receipt file path using `[[NSBundle MainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`. The same, I encode this receipt data and send it to app store for verifying. Of course, the `latest_receipt` is returned. Then I try to send this `latest_receipt` to app store for verify again, I got a very strange result without `latest_receipt_info` and `latest_receipt`. The most weird thing is that the status is 0.

```
{
"status": 0, 
"environment": "Sandbox", 
"receipt": {
    "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox", 
    "adam_id": 0, 
    "bundle_id": "com.abcde.myapp", 
    "application_version": "1.0", 
    "download_id": 0, 
    "request_date": "2013-10-02 02:51:45 Etc/GMT", 
    "request_date_ms": "1380682305478", 
    "request_date_pst": "2013-10-01 19:51:45 America/Los_Angeles", 
    "in_app": [ ]
}
```

Instead, if I always get receipt from `appStoreReceiptURL` and send it to app store, I can get the normal result. But when the subscription expired, status code `21006` will not be returned. This is another weird thing. Do I need to check all the receipts to confirm the validity of user?

Could somebody know what happen? Thanks.

Comment: could you show me a bit of code implementation of getting transaction details in `in-app purchase` in `ios7`?

Comment: See [an answer for the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800461/ios-7-server-receipt-validation-php) and the apple document the question linked.