# Is the transactionReceipt data present in dataWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt

I do IAP receipt verification on server-side.  For this I send `SKPaymentTransaction`' `transactionReceipt`.

Now that `transactionReceipt` is deprecated, I tried to use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]
```

But this is not the same data (so verification of course fails).  It's actually about twice as big, so I thought it could embed the `transactionReceipt` data.

I downloaded Maddy's [VerifyStoreReceiptiOS](https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS), but the code does not supply me the old receipt.

Before I spend much more time on this: Does the `appStoreReceiptURL`'s data indeed include the good ol' `transactionReceipt`?  (And if yes, how can I get it out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ios7 and later the receipt file contains all the transactions that were performed on this apple id for this app on that device. Apple [covers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2) local validation process and the [receipt format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) as well. So yes, you can get a particular transactions info from this file. [WWDC 2104,](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#305) is very helpful on understanding the new receipt format.

Comment: So there is an exact copy of the data/bytes I first got with `transactionReceipt`?

Comment: not sure about the exact copy, but the receipt file definitely contains all the purchase information. i've misread your question, you want to make a server-side validation, that's even [more simple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1). All you have to do is to send the whole file to apple and it will perform verification itself and your server will receive a correct answer.

Comment: One more moment, the receipt file holds only non-consumables. consumable transactions will not be regenerated in the receipt after app reinstallation.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870208/1254172) answer provides some info how you can handle apple's validation answer

Comment: I already have a working server-side; I'm trying to avoid changes/work on server-side. That's why I'm trying to get a singular receipt.

Comment: well, I'm not really sure if the new receipt format contains the same data inside each container, i've never implemented IAP on ios6. But you may try to load the receipt, find the container for the particular productId and then read an opaque value, that might be the value you looking for. The library you've mentioned allows to browse the receipt contents. Maybe [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-17/receipt-validation.html) will help you in understanding.

Comment: IMHO, the much simpler solution would be to have a 2 separate scripts on server-side, each for a different receipt format. There's a lot of ready implementations of receipt validation.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. I've indeed decided to handle the difference on server-side.